# How to import/export chrome data without any 3rd party applications/extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Is there any way to import/export Google Chrome cookies from one browser or session without any third party applications?

All the methods I searched involved usage of a third party extension or tool.

Comment: Go to C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default, copy cookies or anything else you wish to backup. On a new install of chrome, copy and paste them back into the same folder (chrome must be closed)